# How to separate scanner from business logic

Tags: java

I'm trying to create something but so far don't like the way I'm achieving it.

I have `Main class` also I have `package entity` for `Product` class and `services package` for `TaxService interface` and `TaxServiceImpl class`.

In my `TaxServiceImpl` I have this method:

```
 @Override
public void changeTaxPercentage(Product p) {
    System.out.println("Enter new tax percentage");
    double newTax = scanner.nextDouble();
    double calculateTax = (p.getPrice() * (newTax / 100));
    double result = calculateTax + p.getPrice();
    System.out.println("Calculation finished");
    System.out.printf("Product price reported as $%.2f before tax and $%.2f after %.0f%% tax.\n", p.getPrice(), result, p.getTax());
}
```

As you can see there is some calculations and I want to somehow remove that scanner from there since I want that this class is just used for logic, how I can achieve this so somehow I ask user on another way for new double and then use that double in this method.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, and from what I understand you want to use `Scanner` just not inside the `changeTaxPercentage()` function.
Why you do not just pass it as an argument ?

```
System.out.println("Enter new tax percentage");
double newTax = scanner.nextDouble();
changeTaxPercentage(p, newTax);
```

---

```
@Override
public void changeTaxPercentage(Product p, double newTax) {
    double calculateTax = (p.getPrice() * (newTax / 100));
    double result = calculateTax + p.getPrice();
    System.out.println("Calculation finished");
    System.out.printf("Product price reported as $%.2f before tax and $%.2f after %.0f%% tax.\n", p.getPrice(), result, p.getTax());
}
```